# Does drafting affect things other than speed?

Tags: forza-motorsport-5

In Forza 5, you can draft opponents to relieve some drag and gain some more speed. Does this have any other affects on your car?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, drafting has many other affects on your car. for example:

- the lowered amount of drag means you have less downforce. Your braking and grip take a pretty noticeable hit when you draft into tight corners at high speeds
- when you leave the draftstream your car may lurch because of the sudden change in drag (only noticiable on the really high powered cars, and with certain assists turned off [namely steering assist])
- your fuel efficiency is improved as your car doesn't have as much air friction. (really only noticeable in endurance races)

On long straights you should definitely draft, but as you come up to corners leave the draftstream so you have your downforce and grip which is essential for proper cornering. when, where, and how to leave the stream is entirely situational to the track/corner/conditions/opponent position, though.